# Sed carriage return in realtime

Tags: sed, carriage-return

So basically i have this:

```
 while true; do printf "%s\r" $(date +"%H:%M:%S"); sleep 1; done | sed s/"\(^[^$]*$\)"/"[test] \1"/g
```

The goal of this example is to print the date on this same line using carriage return, then filter the ouput through sed to prepend [test] to the line as if i was using

```
 `printf "[test] %s\r" $(date)`
```

but instead sed outputs nothing. I've tried `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` and they haven't worked or i'm not using them correctly. I want to get this to work using `ffmpeg` but more importantly any kind of output that uses a carriage return.

Comment: Can you make it clearer what you're trying to do?

Comment: basically prepend [ffmpeg] to every line in ffmpeg output. It works for every line except the ones with carriage return.

Comment: Please read ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: read and understood but im not clear what that has to do with my question

Comment: You have provided some code but you haven't said what's wrong with what it currently does and you haven't asked a question. It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to workaround:

```
while true; do printf "%s\n" $(date +"%H:%M:%S"); sleep 1; done|awk '{printf("[test]%s\r",$0)}'
```

When you use `printf "%s\r"`, you are printing string out in one line, that means the line will never ends, but `sed` will work only then a line ends(means this line is complete). I think that's why your code not work.

You'd better let the last command print lines into one.

Comment: while that works for the example, the goal is not to change the printf but leave it as is and pipe it through sed (or awk if it works) because i can't change the output of ffmpeg or other programs that use \r.